# How are custom events in JavaScript different from simply calling regular functions?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

For example, I have read this article by David Walsh:

https://davidwalsh.name/customevent

```
// Trigger it!
myElement.dispatchEvent(myEvent);
```

As the author summarizes at the end of the article:

> Creating and trigger custom events with custom data is incredibly useful. Not only can you create your own naming convention for events, but you may also pass custom data along the way!

#### The way I understand it:

Unlike triggering an event from outside of our program, like when scrolling on a page, seemingly all the above example is doing, is calling a function manually at a certain point in the program.

I could see, how this might be a way of organizing a program, a design pattern, but am I missing something else here?

Comment: I think the idea is to create a meaningful *name* for what is happening in a program so that anyone can consume and extend it. For example you could say vim's `autocmd` is an example of this design pattern. As an API's publisher you just *publish* the event, as an API consumer, you just *attach* to it. All that API publisher can say is that so and so thing has happened. You can extend it, the way you want it to be.

Comment: I guess it's mostly about the pattern. You can for instance attach multiple listeners to the same event independently, and triggering the event will fire all of them. Here's an article I found: https://css-tricks.com/custom-events-are-pretty-cool/

Comment: From the link OP posted: «_Creating and trigger custom events with custom data is incredibly useful. Not only can you create your own naming convention for events, but you may also pass custom data along the way!_»

Comment: Martin Fowler's talk on event driven programming is somewhat related to this concept. You can watch it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STKCRSUsyP0&vl=en

Comment: @GrafiCode Thanks, I have added the quote to the question.

Comment: "*calling a function manually*" - an event doesn't call a single function. It might trigger multiple or none, depending on how many are listening. So yes, it's definitely just [a certain pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish–subscribe_pattern), but a pattern that is more powerful than directly calling a specific function.

Comment: It's a pattern, like Singleton, Decorator etc. As such it is a relatively generic solution to a certain class of situations that happen frequently. If you remove all abstractions you are left with purely imperative code without any functions and only gotos. Some abstractions are baked into a language, others can be built by the programs themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The custom events in Javascript are an implementation of the observer-pattern, where the the listeners are grouped by the event-name.

Quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

> ## What problems can the Observer design pattern solve?
>
> The Observer pattern addresses the following problems:
>
> - A one-to-many dependency between objects should be defined without making the objects tightly coupled.
> - It should be ensured that when one object changes state an open-ended number of dependent objects are updated automatically.
> - It should be possible that one object can notify an open-ended number of other objects.
>
> Defining a one-to-many dependency between objects by defining one object (subject) that updates the state of dependent objects directly is inflexible because it couples the subject to particular dependent objects. Tightly coupled objects are hard to implement, change, test, and reuse because they refer to and know about (how to update) many different objects with different interfaces.
>
> ## What solution does the Observer design pattern describe?
>
> - Define Subject and Observer objects.
> - so that when a subject changes state, all registered observers are notified and updated automatically.
>
> The sole responsibility of a subject is to maintain a list of observers and to notify them of state changes by calling their update() operation. 
>   The responsibility of observers is to register (and unregister) themselves on a subject (to get notified of state changes) and to update their state (synchronize their state with subject's state) when they are notified. 
>   This makes subject and observers loosely coupled. Subject and observers have no explicit knowledge of each other. Observers can be added and removed independently at run-time.
>   This notification-registration interaction is also known as publish-subscribe.

While the loosely coupled code with custom events is super flexible, the process-flow quickly can become opaque, if they are used in an unstructured and excessive way.

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN About custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) - they mainly used for creating **synthetic events**.

> ...Such events are commonly called **synthetic events**, as opposed to the
>   events fired by the browser itself.

**Synthetic event** is a cross-browser wrapper around the browser’s native event. It gives the developer more control, and making it possible to add extra functionality which not exist in standard native events, like adding extra data, like suggested in David Walsh's article.

Another usage for synthetic events is creating event's pool, so you can reuse events instead of creating them from scratch. [React is using that method](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling) under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

This is a generic explanation, but I think it useful to understand the idea behind event driven architecture.

**TL;DR**

You can use custom events if you want your program to be **extended** by **someone** else according to their needs; usually this happens at some kind of framework level where you can't predict the final behavior of an application.

---

An event has three parts associated to it - defining, triggering and attaching.

The browser exposes a lot of inbuilt events like `onload` etc which can be used to customize the behavior of your browser. Here, the "defining" and "triggering" part is done by the browser (developer) for you. You as a **consumer** can extend it by attaching functions to it.

So, why did the browser think of creating an event and calling it `onload`? Why couldn't it call `fetchMySuperContent`? Because the browser **wanted** to give you an **ability** to **extend** it with any function(s) of your choice; and the **best name** it could give was **onload** because that's what is happening under the hood! You could **magically** attach it **anywhere** in your program to modify the behavior of the browser -- since it programmed to call anything that is attached to it. This ubiquity is what makes it super easy and useful. It can't guess that `fetchMySuperContent` is what you wanted to do; also someone else could do something else.

I think you could say this is the purpose of custom events as well; except here the author is the framework developer and consumer is someone like you or me to who wishes to extend it.

It is a nice example of the power of *indirection*, and *separation of concern*.

Comment: This is similar to the idea of "hooks" in some programming environments, like Emacs Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom event gives you access to the event object that has it's own properties and methods. If you don't need to use those properties or methods you should call a regular function and not trigger it as a custom event.

Here is the documentation for event that specifies the properties and methods:
[Events in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)